# HTTP POST with Spring HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I have a Spring Boot Application and I am using Spring HATEOAS to provide REST Services.

I have my Resources and ResourceAssemblers. In ResourceAssemblers the mapping to the resource happens (toResource method from ResourceAssemblerSupport). So I can handle all GET Requests without any problem.

Now I want to POST some data. In RequestBody I expect also a Resource and in ResourceAssembler I added an extra methode (toModel) to map to domain-model.

But the thing is, that the Resource has Links. If I want to POST data via Swagger in example value block it shows a model like below

```
"person": {
    "_links": [
      {
        "deprecation": "string",
        "href": "string",
        "hreflang": "string",
        "media": "string",
        "rel": "string",
        "templated": true,
        "title": "string",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "field1": "string",
    "field2": "string",
    "field3": "string",
    "field4": "string",
    "field5": 0,
    "field6": "string"
  }
```

If I execute there is an exception:

```
JSON parse error: Expected relation name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Expected relation name
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 5] (through reference chain:rest.resource.PersonResource["_links"])]
```

What I am doing wrong? Should I use an extra DTO in RequestBody instead of Resource? What is the best way to make POST request using **Spring HATEOAS**?

Comment: Something is wrong with the `json` you have given. `_links` generally has an immediate ref name .. for example `"_links:{ "self": { "href": ....}}}`

Comment: @ringbearer if I execute GET via Swagger you are right in response there is a ref name but in POST there isn´t. Should I use in POST a DTO instead of Resource ?

Comment: [spring-hateoas-sample](https://github.com/opencredo/spring-hateoas-sample) here is an example project. POST does not except Resource but a DTO. But I still wanted to be sure what the standard in Spring HATEOAS is.

Comment: Yes. Look up a few samples how it is done(Link from spring's source) : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas-examples/blob/master/affordances/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/examples/EmployeeController.java

Comment: Unfortunately, this example does not answer what I need because there is no dto just entity without any mapping

Comment: Yes, the example does not show transforming an input object to the data layer object, which is fine. However, the example shows that on `POST` you would simply accept an object that represents your POST JSON structure. Also, note that it does not make any sense to provide the `_link` as the links are not created yet!!